# Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i have a problem with this eloquent. how i can pass only the blog that have the attribute categoryid that same as the id that clicked from index.blade.php ?

[This is the code of show function in CategoryController.php, the parameter is the id and comes from the index.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W0op.png)

[This is the picture of show.blade.php , the page after click button from index.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJl0h.png)

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Don't post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)!

Comment: i am sorry, its my first time posting question here as i very blank about this solution. Will improve for the next post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `get()` method after the `where` method on your CategoryController, something like this:

```
return view('categories.show', [
    'category' => $category,
    'blog' => Blog::where('categoryid', $category->id)->get(),
]);
```